# WordPress pagination fuction in shortcode always displayed on the top

Tags: php, wordpress, function, pagination, shortcode

WordPress pagination function in shortcode always displayed on the top. Please have a look on below code

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Custom Pagination */
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function suareztheme_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2){

    $showitems = ( $range * 2 ) + 1;  

    global $paged;
    if(empty($paged)) 
        $paged = 1;

    if($pages == ''){

        global $wp_query;
        $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

        if(!$pages){

            $pages = 1;
        }
    }

    if( 1 != $pages ){

        $pagination_html .= '<div class="pagination">';

        if( $paged > 2 && $paged > $range + 1 && $showitems < $pages ){

            $pagination_html .= '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link( 1 ) . '">&laquo;</a>';

        }

        if( $paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages ){

            $pagination_html .= '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link( $paged - 1 ) . '">&lsaquo;</a>';

        }

        for ( $i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++ ){

            if ( 1 != $pages && ( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems )){

                if ( $paged == $i ){

                    $pagination_html .= '<span class="current">' . $i . '</span>';

                } else{

                    $pagination_html .= '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link( $i ). '" class="inactive">' . $i . '</a>';

                }
            }

        }

        if ( $paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages ){

            $pagination_html .= '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link( $paged + 1 ) . '">&rsaquo;</a>';

        }

        if ( $paged < $pages - 1 &&  $paged + $range - 1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages ){

            $pagination_html .= '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link( $pages ) . '">&raquo;</a>';

        }

        $pagination_html .= '</div>';

        return $pagination_html;
    }

}
```

Then I called it in the shortcode function.

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Grid Shortcode */
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function RecentBlog($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "comments" => 'true',
        "date" => 'true',
        "columns" => '4',
        "limit" => '-1',
        "title" => 'true',
        "description" => 'true',
        "cat_slug" => '',
        "post_type" => '',
        "excerpt_length" => '15',
        "readmore_text" => '',
        "pagination" => 'false'
    ), $atts));

    global $post;

    $postformat = get_post_format();

    ....

    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('page');
    } else {
        $paged = 1;
    }

    ......

    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        $postformat = get_post_format();
            if( $postformat == "" ) $postformat="standard";

        $protected = "";

        $portfoliogrid .= '<div class="' . $column_no . ' post grid-post post-' . $postformat . '">';

            .....////

            $portfoliogrid .= '<div class="summary-info">';
                .......
            $portfoliogrid .='</div>';

            // If either of title and description needs to be displayed.
            if ( $title == "true" || $description == "true" ) {

                $portfoliogrid .='<div class="work-details">';
                ......
                $portfoliogrid .='</div>';

            }

        $portfoliogrid .='</div>';

    endwhile; endif;

    if ( $pagination == "true" ){

        if ( isset( $additional_loop ) ){

            echo suareztheme_pagination( $additional_loop->max_num_pages );

        } else {

            echo suareztheme_pagination();

        }

        if ( function_exists("suareztheme_pagination") ) {
        } else {

            next_posts_link('&laquo;&laquo; Older Posts');
            previous_posts_link('Newer Posts &raquo;&raquo;');

        }

    }
    wp_reset_query();
    return $portfoliogrid;
}

add_shortcode( "recentblog", "RecentBlog" );
```

The above code is working fine , but it has one problem, when it display in specific page, it always displayed on the top regardless it's place. So appreciate your support to help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the shortcode callback, you need to concatenate and return the html, e.g.:

```
$portfoliogrid .= suareztheme_pagination();
```

Note that you'll have to use `get_next_posts_link()` and `get_previous_posts_link()` instead of `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()`.

Comment: Thanks @diggy so much. It's working perfectly now. One more question that when should I use ob_start(), there are tuts recommend to add it before and after the function. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. No need to use output buffering, unless you're unable to return the data you need.

Comment: Hi @diggy My problem still appearing, it's working good except the `a` tag display on top, you can check my site here: http://128.199.180.6/demo/blog/blog-grid/

Comment: And this is my code for this part:

`if ( $readmore_text != '' || $comments == "true" || $vote == "true" ) {
$portfoliogrid .= '<div class="entry-links">';
$portfoliogrid .= '<div class="entry-links-left">';
$portfoliogrid .= dot_irecommendthis();
$portfoliogrid .= '<span class="entry-comments"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>' . comments_popup_link('Leave a Reply', '1', '%') . '</span>';
$portfoliogrid .= '</div>';
}`

Comment: `dot_irecommendthis()` echoes html, as does `comments_popup_link()` (See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17763), so you'll have to use output buffering (`ob_` stuff) to have the html returned.

Comment: There is another way that you can use a custom function `get_comments_popup_link` has written by @Otto, which you can find on [his personal site](http://www.thescubageek.com/code/wordpress-code/add-get_comments_popup_link-to-wordpress) to overcome my issue. Thank you so much :)